# which programs can change the $PATH on MAC os?

Tags: python, macos, path, python-3.4

I am trying to install Python 3.4.3 on top of Python 2.7.4 . The tutorial I am following mentioned that at the /etc/paths folder should have the /usr/local/bin path first. Mine looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

So it seems to be ok but when I run

```
echo $PATH
```

I am getting this sting:

/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/my_name/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/Applications/Dev Desktop/drush

It seems to me that something is not quite right there. Any ideas?

Comment: `/opt/local/bin` looks like MacPorts

Comment: I would actually recommend using MacPorts for Python 3; installing Python 3 side-by-side with the system default Python 2.7 can cause problems and confusion, MacPorts is one means of alleviating some of that.

Comment: thanks a lot. that helped!